# How can I bring back indicator-messages?

Tags: indicator, indicator-message

For some reasons, `indicator-messages` is not showing up despite being installed. Neither can I find it using the auto-completion for `indicator-`.

What can I try to bring it back?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something went wrong when you tried to test and tweak things in the Ubuntu Unity desktop environment - and I know that you are doing this extensively and very often - thus remove the indicator completely (including the configuration files) and reboot the system :

`sudo apt purge indicator-messages`| `sudo reboot`

Reinstall it (the reason for restart is, that `indicator-messages` is an "autostart service") :

`sudo apt install indicator-messages` | `sudo reboot`

Now everything should work as expected again (if nothing else is broken from "testings").

Also check whether `gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.messages applications`
returns correct application entries such as the default setting `['thunderbird.desktop']`.

Comment: I think I found the problem! I had removed [https://lzone.de/liferea/](https://lzone.de/liferea/) but its desktop entry remained in the dconf configuration of indicator-messages.

Comment: I had to remove `liferea.desktop` from the dconf-editor entry `com/canonical/indicator/messages/applications` and add back `thunderbird.desktop`. Thanks for your help!